# Missing column values

Tags: python, numpy, multiple-columns

I have merged ten txt files(A_1,A_2......A_10 and B_1,B_2.....B_10) horizontally and got the output as A_B_1,A_B_2......A_B_3........ The issue is File A's has large and fixed number of rows (4320) while B's has smaller and fluctuating number of rows(2689,3078...), So whenever I try to load the merged file using numpy, I am facing a wrong number of columns error starting from the line when B's have no values. Any suggestion on how to solve this issue would be appreciated.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib notebook
data=np.loadtxt('/Users/Hrihaan/Desktop/Code/A_B_5.txt')
time=data[:,1]
V=data[:,3]
plt.plot(time,V)
```

[image: Missing Column Values at the point when B values end]

Comment: Post the code you used.

Comment: I did, I was just trying to plot from 2 different columns@SamCraig

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have a file named "A_B_5.txt". 
The contents are:

```
3044 1995 9.0 3.8 3044 1995 9.0 3.8 
3044 1995 9.0 3.8 3044 1995 9.0 3.8 
3044 1995 9.0 3.8 3044 1995 9.0 3.8 
3044 1995 9.0 3.8
3044 1995 9.0 3.8
3044 1995 9.0 3.8
```

You can use `read_table` from `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd
data= pd.read_table("A_B_5.txt", sep="\s+", header=None).values
```

You'll get:

```
array([[ 3044. ,  1995. , 9. , 3.8,  3044. ,  1995. , 9. , 3.8],
   [ 3044. ,  1995. , 9. , 3.8,  3044. ,  1995. , 9. , 3.8],
   [ 3044. ,  1995. , 9. , 3.8,  3044. ,  1995. , 9. , 3.8],
   [ 3044. ,  1995. , 9. , 3.8, nan, nan, nan, nan],
   [ 3044. ,  1995. , 9. , 3.8, nan, nan, nan, nan],
   [ 3044. ,  1995. , 9. , 3.8, nan, nan, nan, nan]])
```

======

Read a list of files `A_B_i.txt` for `i` in `1,2,... 10`:

```
data =[pd.read_table("A_B_"+i+".txt", sep="\s+", header=None).values 
for i in range(1,11)]
```

And access each data frame like `data[0]`,`data[1]` etc.

Comment: It's not working, saying the file doesn't exist but I have checked, the file is in that folder.

Comment: @Hrihaan Do you have pandas installed? Or try run the code in the same dir with the data.

Comment: Yes Huang, I use Anaconda, so that has pandas, can you suggest me a way where I can replace all the blank spaces with nan, I have tried many kinds of stuff with no luck yet.

Comment: Huang, it worked, will you please suggest some way in which I can do these for multiple txt files using a loop and save them also?